# Google Analytics doesn't report Real-time Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I'm debugging my app with Google Analytics but when I start my app, (some time later) I check Google Analytics and it doesnt appear anyone in real-time.

I have two accounts with Google Analytics. If I link the app with the old one, which is working perfectly, I can see how appear one more device in real-time section. But if I link the app with the new one, Google Analytics doesn't report any new device in real-time.

So, I think that the source of the app is right and the problem exists in somewhere inside the Google Anaylitics Accounts.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Google Analytics needs one day to activate your account.

Now, it's working fine.

Thanks.